# TypeError: lemmatize() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'index', 'exceptions', and 'rules'

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy, data-cleaning, lemmatization

I'm working with text data right now and I'm preprocessing it (I'm working with French data text).

Here's my code so far:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', sep=';')

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

import re
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from spacy.lang.fr import French


stop_words = set(stopwords.words('french'))
tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
lemmatizer = French.Defaults.create_lemmatizer()


def clean_text(text):
    text = text.lower()  
    text = tokenizer.tokenize(text)
    text = [word for word in text if not word in stop_words]
    text = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in text]
    final_text = ' '.join( [w for w in text if len(w)>2] ) 
    return final_text

df['comms_clean'] = df['comms'].apply(lambda x : clean_text(x))
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: lemmatize() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'index', 'exceptions', and 'rules'
```

I'm used to work with English data so it's the first time I used this kind of packages so I'm quite lost.  What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The error you have shown is telling you that those arguments are missing when you call it, so you need them to call method `lemmatize()` but you are only passing one: `lemmatize(string=word)`.

Here you have the official documentation: https://spacy.io/api/lemmatizer#_title

Here you have the implementation of the lemmatizer object where you can find the `lemmatize` method: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lemmatizer.py

```
def lemmatize(self, string, index, exceptions, rules):
```

Comment: Yeah but I don't know what I need to put in those arguments actually, that's the main problem :) I usually don't use this library at all, I use stemmer